# Excel Visual Basic SpinButton1 does not work on second search

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table with name and age and a command button, this button opens the customer search screen. When I search for the name Andrew brings me 3 results, I go to page 3 of 3 and perform a new search, so the arrow doesn't work, do you know where the error might be?

[image]

```
    Public MatrizResultados As Variant
Public Total_Ocorrencias As Long


Private Sub btn_Procurar_Click()

    If Me.txt_Procurar.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox "Enter a name"
    Else
        Call ProcuraPersonalizada(Me.txt_Procurar.Text)
    End If
    
End Sub

Private Sub Label6_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub Label7_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub SpinButton1_Change()
Dim Linha As Long
Dim TotalOcorrencias As Long


    TotalOcorrencias = SpinButton1.Max + 1
    Linha = MatrizResultados(SpinButton1.Value)
    
    Label_Registros_Contador.Caption = SpinButton1.Value + 1 & " de " & TotalOcorrencias
    TextBox1.Text = Plan1.Cells(Linha, 1).Value
    TextBox2.Text = Plan1.Cells(Linha, 2).Value

    
End Sub


Private Sub ProcuraPersonalizada(ByVal TermoPesquisado As String)
Dim Busca As Range
Dim Primeira_Ocorrencia As String
Dim Resultados As String

    'perform the search
    Set Busca = Plan1.Cells.Find(What:=TermoPesquisado, After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    
    
    If Not Busca Is Nothing Then
    
        Primeira_Ocorrencia = Busca.Address
        Resultados = Busca.Row
    

        Do
            Set Busca = Plan1.Cells.FindNext(After:=Busca)
        

            If Not Busca.Address Like Primeira_Ocorrencia Then
                Resultados = Resultados & ";" & Busca.Row
            End If
        Loop Until Busca.Address Like Primeira_Ocorrencia
    
    
        MatrizResultados = Split(Resultados, ";")

        SpinButton1.Max = UBound(MatrizResultados)
        

        SpinButton1.Enabled = True
        

        Label_Registros_Contador.Caption = "1 de " & UBound(MatrizResultados) + 1
        
        

        TextBox1.Text = Plan1.Cells(MatrizResultados(0), 1).Value
        TextBox2.Text = Plan1.Cells(MatrizResultados(0), 2).Value

    Else
    
        SpinButton1.Enabled = False
        Label_Registros_Contador.Caption = ""
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        TextBox2.Text = ""

        MsgBox "No results for '" & TermoPesquisado & "' was found."
    
    End If
    txt_Procurar.Text = ""
    txt_Procurar.SetFocus
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    SpinButton1.Enabled = False
    Label_Registros_Contador.Caption = ""
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to reset the Spin button, it thinks its still on entry 3 of 3 (you can reverse through the options and then it will be correct when you try and go forwards again).

Add this line:

```
SpinButton1.Value = 0
```

Somewhere before you start messing with it, I put it:

```
        MatrizResultados = Split(Resultados, ";")
        SpinButton1.Value = 0
        SpinButton1.Max = UBound(MatrizResultados)
```